# How do I do a matrix multiplication on the last 2 dimensions of a tensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

Say I have a shape (3, 5, 3) tensor like so:

```
  x = [[[ 4.,  6.,  6.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  3.],
    [ 6.,  6.,  5.],
    [ 4.,  1.,  8.],
    [ 3.,  6.,  7.]],

   [[ 4.,  0.,  5.],
    [ 4.,  7.,  2.],
    [ 4.,  5.,  3.],
    [ 4.,  2.,  1.],
    [ 3.,  4.,  4.]],

   [[ 0.,  3.,  4.],
    [ 6.,  7.,  5.],
    [ 1.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 3.,  8.,  3.],
    [ 8.,  5.,  7.]]]
```

And a shape `(3, 3, 4)` tensor like so:

```
y = [[[ 3.,  2.,  5.,  4.],
    [ 8.,  7.,  1.,  8.],
    [ 4.,  0.,  5.,  3.]],

   [[ 8.,  7.,  7.,  3.],
    [ 5.,  4.,  0.,  1.],
    [ 6.,  5.,  4.,  4.]],

   [[ 7.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
    [ 7.,  5.,  0.,  6.],
    [ 7.,  5.,  4.,  1.]]]
```

How would do a matrix multiplication so that the resulting matrix is of shape `(3, 5, 4)`

Whereby the first element of the matrix is given by the matrix multiplication of

```
[[ 4.,  6.,  6.],
[ 0.,  0.,  3.],
[ 6.,  6.,  5.],
[ 4.,  1.,  8.],
[ 3.,  6.,  7.]]
```

and

```
[[ 3.,  2.,  5.,  4.] 
 [ 8.,  7.,  1.,  8.]
 [ 4.,  0.,  5.,  3.]]
```

I've tried using `tf.tensordot` like:

```
z = tf.tensorflow(x, y, axes = [[2],[1]])
```

which I believe is multiply the 3rd axis of `x` with the 2nd axis of `y` but it gives me a tensor of shape `(3, 5, 3, 4)`. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a typo on the example, you put `tf.tensorflow` and not `tf.tensordot`. But as it is only that StackOverflow doesn't let me change it.

Answer (score 3):

Silly me after reading `tf.matmul` docs it seems like since the inner dimensions match I can just do `tf.matmul(x,y)` and it gives me the answer